# MYSQL - Period Table to Normal "Year-Month-00"

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to turn the following info into a usable date field.

I have the following:

```
Date      |Period|Product

0000-00-00|   31 |Skies

0000-00-00|  17  |Shoes

0000-00-00|   4  |Etc...
```

The period is the number of monthis since the April Financial Year.

```
        Apri|May|June|July|Augu|Sept|Octo|Nove|Dece|Janu|Febu|Marc
2012   |1   |2  |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |8   |9   |10  |11  |12    (Ends March 2013)

2011   |13  |14 |15  |16  |17  |18  |19  |20  |21  |22  |23  |24    (Ends March 2012)

2010   |25  |26 |27  |28  |29  |30  |31  |32  |33  |34  |35  |36    (Ends March 2011)
```

What im looking for as a result is

```
Date      |Period|Product

2010-10-00|   31 |Skies

2011-08-00|  17  |Shoes

2012-07-00|   4  |Etc...
```

Ive tried DateDiff but since the Period sheet im working from is backwards (and the worst thing I have ever seen)  DateDiff doesn't do what I need.

The reason it's not doing what i need is that the month after period 24 (2011-03) is Period 1 (2011-04)  So its not sequential.  Its just down right stupid.  Same applies to period 36 (2010-03) next period is 25 (2010-04)

Anyone who can solve this earns my instant respect.  Good gods this has been painful to work out.

Working in MYSQL, but happy to take on any solution.
Thanks

(Thanks to the person who edited the stuff for me, I could not find how to give the text a decent layout.)

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little better? Does the `period` field represent the number of months since the month of April **of a specific year**? Could you show us an example result-set that you would ideally like to have?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure If I understand your question correctly but you can simply add months to a date with mysql's [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function (and manipulate them using [other date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html))

So april 2012 with 4 added to it gives you august, which is what you're looking for, right?

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CONCAT(2012,'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH),
MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(2012,'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH));


+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(CONCAT(2012,'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH) | MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(2012,'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) |
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-08-01                                       | August                                                      |
  +--------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

edit: I get the impression that what you want to calculate might be rather the data given from the current year april - the months in your table, that would be done with [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub). As you can see you can just use the YEAR() and NOW() functions to get the current year.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH),
MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH));


+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH) | MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-04-01'),INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2011-12-01                                              | December                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Calculating the months between 2 dates is done with [PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff), it needs a specific format though and months with only 1 digit will need 0 prepended.

```
SELECT 
PERIOD_DIFF(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'04'),    -- year + '04' for YYYYMM
            CONCAT(YEAR('2011-08-01'),   -- year YYYY
                   IF(MONTH('2011-08-01') < 10, -- got 2 digits for month?
                       CONCAT('0',MONTH('2011-08-01')), -- no, prepend '0' 
                       MONTH('2011-08-01')) -- yes just return month
             )
) AS difference;

+------------+
| difference |
+------------+
|          8 |
+------------+
```

Finally found after I let my brain rest, it was one of those forest -  trees things. ;)

```
SET @period=15;  

SELECT DATE_ADD(  -- use date_add so we can go back and forwards in time
  CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()) - FLOOR(IF(@period < 10,0,IF(@period < 12,-1,@period/12 - IF(@period%12 = 0,2,0))) ) ,'-03-01'), -- start from march this year so +1  equals april, subtract 1 year per 12 months
INTERVAL
 IF(@period%12 < 10,@period%12,@period%12 - 12) -- ignore the full years, if rest < 10 add (APR - DEC) else subtract (rest - 12 to get negative number)
MONTH) 
AS result;
```

this will always return the correct date in 1 swoop, I guarantee. :)

Comment: Thanks that was useful to know about, unfortunately since the periods are not in a straight order its not as simple as date-x.

Comment: how are they done then? There must be some correlation somewhere?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure myself.  Its almost as though the guys who made this didn't understand it themselves.

I'm starting to form a solution.  I have this so far, and I think this will work.  just not sure of the exact syntax myself..

SELECT Period, (Period-12) AS NP, DATE_ADD(2011-03-01, Interval ((Period)-12) Month) FROM Sales WHERE Period < 25 AND PERIOD >12 GROUP BY Period ORDER BY Period ASC

Result:
Period   NP  DATE_ADD
13          1  NULL

Comment: oh so it's a dynamic lookup table type of thing

Comment: GOT IT!!!

Finally after 3 days of working on this one darn thing...

Thanks Harald, bringing me back to the basic's of it :)  Was simple enough in the end, I just need to move my "WHERE" clause by 12 months at a time, and I can work out Year and Month from the multiple of 12 that I needed to subtract.  Yay!  finally

Comment: Ahh I don't know what a Dynamic lookup table is?

Comment: I can do it via (number - 1)%12 + 4 what have you found?

Comment: SELECT Period, (Period-12) AS NP, DATE_ADD('2011-03-01', Interval (Period) Month) FROM Sales WHERE Period < 25 AND PERIOD >12 GROUP BY Period ORDER BY Period ASC                                                                                                                                            The WHERE Clause moves the "Year" If its between 1 and 12, its this year, if its 13 to 24 its Last year etc.  Just means running several queries.

Comment: Still didn't work unfortunatly.  IT worked for Period 5,17,29,41 but it didn't work for any of the others. (going up to Period 48)

Seriously messed up thing they created there.  Ill stick with the solution I have, and thank God I'm rid of it.

Thanks it was good to be able to share and discuss the issue.

Comment: you should check my final solution now, I'm like 99.99% sure. :P 1 query.